# Importing URL Data comes Under One Index - Python

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to import data from the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Association. The data can be downloaded manually in txt format, but I want to download it via Python's urlopen. After importing the data, all columns and rows are inside a single index column, rather a standard dataframe with headers. Any information would be helpful.

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/view_text_file.php?filename=42887h2014.txt.gz&dir=data/historical/stdmet/"
#df = pd.read_csv(url, header=NONE, sep='\s+')
data_csv = urlopen(url)
df2014 = pandas.read_csv(data_csv, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

df2014.head()
```

Result:

```
df2014.head()
Out[26]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [#yr  mo dy hr mn degT m/s  m/s     m   sec   sec degT   hPa  degC  degC  degC   mi    ft, 2014 01 01 00 00  61  7.4 99.0  1.12  4.34 99.00 999 9999.0  19.2 999.0  12.5 99.0 99.00, 2014 01 01 00 20  60  7.8 99.0  1.12  4.34 99.00 999 9999.0  19.4 999.0  12.9 99.0 99.00, 2014 01 01 00 40  66  7.8 99.0  1.12  4.34 99.00 999 9999.0  19.3 999.0  13.0 99.0 99.00, 2014 01 01 01 00  76  8.6 99.0  1.18  4.49 99.00 999 9999.0  19.4 999.0  13.3 99.0 99.00]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is that the data source you linked does not separate its data via commas, instead separating them using whitespace. By default, the `read_csv` method in the `pandas` library reads the data assuming commas as the separator.

The solution is simply to set delimiters to whitespaces by setting the `delim_whitespace` argument in `read_csv` to `True`, as such:

```
df2014 = pd.read_csv(data_csv, delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas.read_csv uses ',' as the default delimiter. Your columns are separated by white-spaces. You can tell pandas to use white-spaces as a delimiter either by adding  `sep='\s+'` (as you did in the commented line) or  `delim_whitespace=True` as a keyword argument.
You can find a detailed description of both arguments in the api: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html